# How do I get products by tag and category mysql query

Tags: mysql

I have three tables below

Diagrams:
[image: diagrams]

I want to show the products by category and tag (filter bar)

```
SELECT p.title,
       GROUP_CONCAT(t.property_name)   as tags,
       GROUP_CONCAT(cat.property_name) as cats,
       GROUP_CONCAT(ga.property_name)  as gallery
FROM products p
         INNER JOIN relationships rs ON p.product_id = rs.product_id
         LEFT JOIN properties t ON t.property_id = rs.property_id AND t.property_type = 'tag'
         LEFT JOIN properties cat ON cat.property_id = rs.property_id AND cat.property_type = 'category'
         LEFT JOIN properties ga ON ga.property_id = rs.property_id AND ga.property_type = 'gallery'
where cat.property_name = 'HTML' AND t.property_name ='Tag 1'
GROUP BY p.product_id;
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: `it doesn't work` is not a diagnosis

Comment: That said, if you want a LEFT JOIN (as opposed to an INNER JOIN), then any comparative operators on that LEFT JOINed table should be in  the 'ON' part of the query, not the 'WHERE'

Comment: For further help, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query